# Find particular string Regex

Tags: java, regex

How do I include specific words as a delimiter when I already include them?

Lets say I have a 28 MB TAB-delimited text file (approximately 865,000 records) of the complete transit schedule for the city of Toronto.

But I also don't want the word "complete" in my result.

`inLine.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]+");`

Should I be doing something like this?
`inLine.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]+(complete)");`

```
while (inLine.hasNext()) {
      String word = inLine.next().toLowerCase();
      TreeNode node = bst.findOrInsert(new NodeData(word));
      ListNode p = new ListNode(currentLine);
      p.next = node.data.firstLine;
      node.data.firstLine = p;
}
```

Comment: so you wanna get lines that includes "complete" word ?!

Comment: Can you show some sample records here? So you are trying to avoid rows which is having complete?

Comment: @ShadiJumaa all words except "complete"

Comment: So what I am actually doing is reading reading in a file which is a java program. I am attempting to print all the words from that file except the reserved words

Comment: so let us say you have this string in the file "hello and welcome to complete course in java" if you received word complete then you need to return " hello and welcome to course in java". like this ?

Comment: Yes something like that but I am actually reading in a file and creating a binary tree. Trying to supply a better example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replaceAll method, try this code:

```
    String wordToReplace = "complete"; //word that you need to exclude
    String fileContent = "hello and welcome to complete course in java";    
    String result = fileContent.replaceAll(wordToReplace, "");
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: `replaceAll` is actually unnecessary. Just `replace` will achieve the same effect, and is a bit of a misnomer :)  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: replace and replaceAll doing the same. as we were talking about the regex I added the replaceAll, anyways thanks for your nice catch.